# Android.Kotlin. Нужна критика кода

Tags: android, инспекция-кода, kotlin

Чтоб изучить Kotlin и android разработку в целом делаю прогоу. Ее целью является заказ угля. Прогу в принципе сделал, но догадываюсь что можно было и лучше. Вот кидаю сюда код двух основных активити чтоб знающие люди посмотрели и в случае чего кинули тапком.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , PlaceSelectionListener
{

companion object {
    private const val PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1
}

/*Оперируемые переменные*/
private var Provider_value:String = "Поставщик не выбран"
private var Coal_value:String = "Уголь не выбран"
private var Coal_price_value:Int = 0
private var Coal_mass_value:Int = 0
private var Address_value:String = ""
private var Distance_value:Int = 0
private var Delivery_price_value:Int = 0
private var Total_price_value:Int = 0
private var Start_ll:LatLng = LatLng(53.716, 91.429)
private var End_ll: LatLng?=null
private var Check: Boolean = false
private var CheckArray: Boolean = true
private var Provider_array = StartArray()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    initializeUI()
}

fun initializeUI() {

    val autocompleteFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment) as PlaceAutocompleteFragment
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this)
    btnPickAddress.setOnClickListener { PlacePickerStart() }
    OneSpinnerContent(Provider_array)
    spinnerListener()
    MassTextListener()

}

override fun onPlaceSelected(p0: Place?) {
    if (p0 != null) {
        End_ll = p0.latLng
        Address_value = p0.address as String
        End_ll?.latitude?.let { End_ll?.longitude?.let { it1 -> LatLng(it, it1) } }?.let { urlRead(LatLng(Start_ll.latitude, Start_ll.longitude), it, "DRIVING") }
    }
}

override fun onError(p0: Status?) {
TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

fun OneSpinnerContent(arg:Array<coalProvider>) {
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<coalProvider>(applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arg)
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
    Provider_Vive_element_text.adapter = adapter
}

fun TwoSpinnerContent(Coal_array: Array<coalProvider.Coal>) {
    val adapterSpTwo = ArrayAdapter<coalProvider.Coal>(applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Coal_array)
    adapterSpTwo.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
    Coal_Vive_element_text.adapter = adapterSpTwo
}

fun spinnerListener(){
    Provider_Vive_element_text.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        if (event.getAction() === MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(CheckArray){
                Provider_array=arrayOfcoalProvider()
                OneSpinnerContent(Provider_array)
                CheckArray=false
            }
        }
        false
    }
    Provider_Vive_element_text.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>, view:View, position:Int, id:Long)
        {
            val spinner_one_selected_item:coalProvider = Provider_Vive_element_text.selectedItem as coalProvider
            spinner_one_selected_item.Provider_latlng?.let { Start_ll = it }
            spinner_one_selected_item.Provider_coal[0].Coal_price?.let { Coal_price_value = it }
            TwoSpinnerContent(spinner_one_selected_item.Provider_coal)
            Provider_value = spinner_one_selected_item.Provider_name.toString()
            if(End_ll !=null){
                End_ll?.latitude?.let { End_ll?.longitude?.let { it1 -> LatLng(it, it1) } }?.let { urlRead(LatLng(Start_ll.latitude, Start_ll.longitude), it, "DRIVING") }
            }
            resUpdate()
            /*Предзданное значение на первую позицию при смене поставщика*/
            OnPiceParceUpdate(spinner_one_selected_item.Provider_coal[0].Coal_price)
        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>) {
        }
    }
    Coal_Vive_element_text.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
    {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>, view:View, position:Int, id:Long) {
            val spinner_two_selected_item:coalProvider.Coal = Coal_Vive_element_text.selectedItem as coalProvider.Coal
            spinner_two_selected_item.Coal_price?.let { Coal_price_value = it }

            Coal_value = spinner_two_selected_item.Coal_name.toString()
            resUpdate()
            Mass_price_Vive_element_text.text = Coal_price_value.toString()
        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>) {
        }
    }
}


fun MassTextListener() {
    Coal_mass_Vive_element_text.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher
    {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, count:Int, after:Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, before:Int, count:Int)
        {
            if (s.isNotBlank()) {
                when (s.toString().toInt()) {
                    0 -> Coal_mass_Vive_element_text.setText("1")
                    !in 1..40 -> Coal_mass_Vive_element_text.setText("40")
                }
                Coal_mass_value = Coal_mass_Vive_element_text.text.toString().toInt()
                resUpdate()
            }

        }
    })
}

fun PlacePickerStart() {

    val builder = PlacePicker.IntentBuilder()
    val latLng = LatLng(53.716, 91.429)
    builder.setLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds.builder().include(latLng).build())
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)  {
    if (requestCode === PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode === AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            val place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this)
            place.latLng?.let { End_ll = it }
            Address_value = place.address as String
            //urlRead(LatLng(0.0,0.0), LatLng(0.0,0.0),"DRIVING")
            End_ll?.latitude?.let { End_ll?.longitude?.let { it1 -> LatLng(it, it1) } }?.let { urlRead(LatLng(Start_ll.latitude, Start_ll.longitude), it, "DRIVING") }
        }
    }

}

fun urlRead (start: LatLng, end: LatLng, mode: String):LatLng {
    val url = ("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=" + mode)
    url.httpGet().responseString { request, response, result ->
        when (result) {
            is Result.Failure -> {
            }

            is Result.Success -> {
                if(jsonParse(result.value).isNotBlank()){
                    Distance_value = jsonParse(result.value).toInt() / 1000
                    resUpdate()
                    Distance_Vive_element_text.text=Distance_value.toString()
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Нет пути", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return end
}

fun jsonParse(res: String):String{
    println("Result: $res")
    val parser: Parser = Parser()
    val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(res)
    val json: JsonObject = parser.parse(stringBuilder) as JsonObject
    var jojo = json.lookup<String?>("routes.legs.distance.value").value.toString()
    return jojo.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
}

fun arrayOfcoalProvider(): Array<coalProvider> {
    val Provider_one = coalProvider("Разрез Аршановский", 0,LatLng(53.402971, 91.083748), Provider_coal = arrayOf(coalProvider.Coal("ДМСШ 0-25/1", 1500),coalProvider.Coal("ДО 25-50", 1700),coalProvider.Coal("ДПК 50-200", 1900),coalProvider.Coal("ДР 0-300 ", 1200)))
    val Provider_two = coalProvider("Разрез Белоярский",  1,  LatLng(53.529799,   91.410684),Provider_coal = arrayOf(coalProvider.Coal("ДМСШ 0-25/2", 1501),coalProvider.Coal("ДО 25-50", 1701),coalProvider.Coal("ДПК 50-200", 1901),coalProvider.Coal("ДР 0-300 ", 1201)))
    val Provider_Three = coalProvider(  "Разрез Черногорский", 2, LatLng(53.759367,   91.061604),Provider_coal = arrayOf(coalProvider.Coal("ДМСШ 0-25/3", 1502),coalProvider.Coal("ДО 25-50", 1702),coalProvider.Coal("ДПК 50-200", 1902),coalProvider.Coal("ДР 0-300 ", 1202)))
    val Provider_four = coalProvider(  "Разрез Восточнобейский", 3, LatLng(53.326586,   91.361016),Provider_coal = arrayOf(coalProvider.Coal("ДМСШ 0-25/4", 1503),coalProvider.Coal("ДО 25-50", 1703),coalProvider.Coal("ДПК 50-200", 1903),coalProvider.Coal("ДР 0-300 ", 1203)))
    val Provider_Five = coalProvider(  "Разрез Изыхский",   4,  LatLng(53.630114,   91.436063),Provider_coal = arrayOf(coalProvider.Coal("ДМСШ 0-25/5", 1504),coalProvider.Coal("ДО 25-50", 1704),coalProvider.Coal("ДПК 50-200", 1904),coalProvider.Coal("ДР 0-300 ", 1204)))
    return arrayOf(Provider_one,Provider_two,Provider_Three,Provider_four,Provider_Five)
}
fun StartArray(): Array<coalProvider> {
    val Provider_Start = coalProvider("Выюерите поставщика", 0,LatLng(0.0, 0.0), Provider_coal = arrayOf(coalProvider.Coal("Поставщик не выбран", null)))
    return arrayOf(Provider_Start)
}

fun resUpdate(){
    if(Address_value.isNotBlank()){
        findViewById<EditText>(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input).setText(Address_value)
    }
    if(Distance_value != 0 && Coal_mass_value != 0){
        when (Coal_mass_value) {
            in 1..3 -> Delivery_price_value =(Distance_value * 10)
            in 4..7 -> Delivery_price_value =(Distance_value * 15)
            in 8..20 -> Delivery_price_value =(Distance_value * 35)
            in 21..40 -> Delivery_price_value =(Distance_value * 80)
            else -> 0f
        }
        Delivery_price_Vive_element_text.text=Delivery_price_value.toString()
    }

    if(Coal_mass_value!=0 && Distance_value!=0 && Coal_price_value!=0){
        Total_price_value = Coal_mass_value * Coal_price_value + Delivery_price_value
        Total_price_Vive_element_text.text = Total_price_value.toString()
        Check = true
    }

}

fun OnPiceParceUpdate(PriceValue: Int?){

    Mass_price_Vive_element_text.text = PriceValue.toString()

}

fun sendMessage(view:View) {
    resUpdate()
    if(Check){
        val intent = Intent(this, miActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(Provider.t, Provider_value.toString())
        intent.putExtra(Coal.t, Coal_value.toString())
        intent.putExtra(Coal_price.t, Coal_price_value.toString())
        intent.putExtra(Coal_mass.t, Coal_mass_value.toString())
        intent.putExtra(Address.t, Address_value.toString())
        intent.putExtra(Delivery_price.t, Delivery_price_value.toString())
        intent.putExtra(Distance.t, Distance_value.toString())
        intent.putExtra(Total_price.t, Total_price_value.toString())
        startActivity(intent)
    }
  }
}
```

Вторая активити с данными заказа. лог и пароль для доступа к сервису отправки смс замазал

```
class miActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var PLC: Int? =null
private var Status:String =""

private var Login: String= "_________"
private var pass: String="___________"
private var PhoneNumProvider: Long = 79131816542
private var PhoneNumUser: String = ""

private var Provider_value :String= ""
private var Coal_value :String= ""
private var Coal_price_value :String= ""
private var Coal_mass_value :String= ""
private var Address_value :String= ""
private var Delivery_price_value :String= ""
private var Distance_value :String= ""
private var Total_price_value :String= ""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.missage)

    val intent = intent
     Provider_value = intent.getStringExtra(Provider.t)
     Coal_value = intent.getStringExtra(Coal.t)
     Coal_price_value = intent.getStringExtra(Coal_price.t)
     Coal_mass_value = intent.getStringExtra(Coal_mass.t)
     Address_value = intent.getStringExtra(Address.t)
     Delivery_price_value = intent.getStringExtra(Delivery_price.t)
     Distance_value = intent.getStringExtra(Distance.t)
     Total_price_value = intent.getStringExtra(Total_price.t)
    bindVive()
    alDig()
    phoneNum()
}

fun alDig(){
    Order_Button_element.setOnClickListener {
        Show_Alert()
    }
}

private fun Show_Alert() {
    alert("Вы уверенны что хотите совершить заказ? ","Подтверждение заказа") {
        positiveButton("Да") {
            toast("You clicked on YES")
            PLC = callNumber(VerificationCode())
            println(PLC.toString())
            VerCode()
        }
        negativeButton("Нет") {
            toast("You clicked on NO")
        }
    }.show()
}

fun callNumber (code:Int): Int {
    val url = ("https://smsc.ru/sys/send.php?"
            + "login=" + "$Login"
            + "&psw=" + "$pass"
            + "&phones=" + "$PhoneNumUser"
            +"&mes="+"$code")
    url.httpGet().responseString { request, response, result ->
        when (result) {
            is Result.Failure -> {
            }

            is Result.Success -> {
            }
        }
    }
    return code
}

private fun VerCode() {
    alert {
        customView {
            verticalLayout {
                //Dialog Title
                toolbar {
                    lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)
                    title = "Код подтверждение"
                }
                val task = editText {
                    hint = "Code hire "
                    padding = dip(20)
                }
                positiveButton("Подтвердить") {
                    if(task.text.toString() == PLC.toString() ){
                        sendMissage()
                        Status="Успешно"
                    }
                    else{
                        Status="Введен не верный код"
                    }
                    alert("$Status","Подтверждение заказа") {
                        positiveButton("Закрыть") {
                        }
                    }.show()
                }
            }
        }
    }.show()
}

fun VerificationCode(): Int {
    fun Random.nextInt(range: IntRange): Int {
        return range.start + nextInt(range.last - range.start)
    }
    val random = Random()
    val verificationCode = random.nextInt(10000..999999)
    return verificationCode
}

fun sendMissage (): Int {
    val url = ("https://smsc.ru/sys/send.php?"
            + "login=" + "$Login"
            + "&psw=" + "$pass"
            + "&phones=" + "$PhoneNumProvider"
            +"&mes="+"" +
            "Поставщик $Provider_value\n" +
            "Уголь     $Coal_value\n" +
            "Цена      $Coal_price_value\n" +
            "Масс      $Coal_mass_value\n" +
            "Адрес     $Address_value\n" +
            "Цена доставки $Delivery_price_value\n" +
            "Дистанция         $Distance_value\n" +
            "Общая стоимость         $Total_price_value")+"&charset="+"utf-8"
    url.httpGet().responseString { request, response, result ->
        when (result) {
            is Result.Failure -> {
            }

            is Result.Success -> {
            }
        }
    }
    return end
}

fun phoneNum(){
    Phone_number_Vive_element_text.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {}

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            val p0 = p0.toString()
            PhoneNumUser = Phone_number_Vive_element_text.text.toString()
        }
    })
}

fun bindVive(){
    Provider_Vive_element_text.text = Provider_value
    Coal_Vive_element_text.text = Coal_value
    Mass_price_Vive_element.text = Coal_price_value
    Coal_mass_Vive_element_text.text = Coal_mass_value
    Address_Vive_element_text.text = Address_value
    Distance_Vive_element_text.text = Distance_value
    Delivery_price_Vive_element_text.text = Delivery_price_value
    Total_price_Vive_element_text.text = Total_price_value
}

}
```

Кст. если кто знает.как отступы между строками в выпадающем окне спинера увеличить(на телефоне хрен попадешь)

Comment: Есть кст такая деталь. Поставил android studio 3.0. И текст в превью спиннера стал белым. в стилях указан стандартный стиль. пробовал проставить цвет текста в разметке и все в пустую. спасла только черная тема из за своего контраста

Comment: Для строк с текстом есть файлы ресурсов, студия должна сама вам об этом сказать. Вообще сначала устраните все замечания IDE (по правому краю полоса с зелеными, желтыми и красными "черточками") потом предлагайте код на рецензию. Думаете кто то должен специально для вас повторять то, на что и так вам указывает среда разработки?

Comment: там в основном предложения переименовать функции и переменные(чтото связанное с регистром)

Comment: @MrBazilevs, вто-вот. С `camelCase` и начните. Потом можно на область видимости методов посмотреть. Не всем нужен public, который в Котлине по умолчанию: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html

Comment: Кстати, вышли официальные Android Kotlin Guides, уже есть с чего начинать https://android.github.io/kotlin-guides/index.html

Comment: В котлине есть оператор """ (три кавычки), который позволяет задавать многострочные строки. Метод `VerCode` перегружен. `alert("$Status","По....` - wtf!? зачем первый аргумент таким образом передаете?. Переменные и методы - с маленькой буквы. `VerificationCode` - `return Random().nextInt(10000..999999)` вместо трех строкю `fun` внутри `fun` - тот еще адок. Вынесите extension function наружу. `val intent = intent`??????